# sum to product formula $\cos(a)\cdot\cos(b) =1/2(\cos (a +b) + \cos(a-b))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am working on orthogonal codes where I have to integrate equations, and I have encountered a problem:

For the equation
$\cos(a)\cdot\cos(b) = 1/2(\cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b))$,
if I put it this way:
$\cos(a) \cdot \cos(b) = 1/2(\cos(a+b) + \cos(b-a))$
or
$\cos(b) \cdot \cos(a) = 1/2(\cos(a+b) + \cos(b-a))$,
will that make any difference?

Comment: In the future, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference formula for Cos(B-A) ? - Trig](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527049/difference-formula-for-cosb-a-trig)

Comment: See this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527049/difference-formula-for-cosb-a-trig/2527063#2527063

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\cos(-a) = \cos(a)$ ($\cos$ is an even function), and $a \times b = b \times a$ (multiplication is commutative)

So the answer is **No**, it will not make a difference.